# Finding base class at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, static-polymorphism

The title almost says everything: Is there a way in C++ to get a class's base type(s) at compile time? I. e. is it possible to hand a class to a template, and let the template use other templates to which it hands the bases of the given class?

My question is not whether I can implement such a functionality myself, there is no question I can (using traits and the like). My question is whether there is some (obscure) builtin functionality that could be used to this end.

Comment: The bottom most base class?

Comment: Actually, I don't even think it's possible to get the list of base classes manually (using standard C++11).

Comment: @Jefffrey Just the next base classes, so that the template could effectively parse the inheritance graph, if it liked. I would already be happy if I could get the first direct base, though.

Comment: *"My question is not whether I can implement such a functionality myself, there is no question I can"* Are you sure? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe the "get" is fairly well defined by the second question sentence in the first paragraph. That is the usecase I was worried about, and that is, what defined a viable solution to me.

Comment: @cmaster: Yeah it looks like I didn't put much effort into parsing that when drunk yesterday. I'd still suggest the question could be clearer to read :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gcc` supports this. See

- [Kerrek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262354/1508519)
- [tr2/type_traits](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++/api/a01610_source.html)
- [Andy Prowl's code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15158714/1508519)
- [n2965](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2965.html)
- [What is the status of N2965 - std::bases and std::direct_bases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435001/what-is-the-status-of-n2965-stdbases-and-stddirect-bases)
- [How to query for all base classes of a class at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281103/how-to-query-for-all-base-classes-of-a-class-at-compile-time)

n2965 provides an example.

> This simple examples illustrates the results of these type traits. In
>   the Suppose we have the following class hierarchy:
>
> ```
> class E {};
> class D {};
> class C : virtual public D, private E {};
> class B : virtual public D, public E {};
> class A : public B, public C {};
> ```
>
> It follows that `bases<A>::type is tuple<D, B, E, C, E>`
>
> Similarly, `direct_bases<A>::type is tuple<B, C>`

Andy Prowl's code example is as follows:

```
#include <tr2/type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
struct dbc_as_tuple { };

template<typename... Ts>
struct dbc_as_tuple<std::tr2::__reflection_typelist<Ts...>>
{
    typedef std::tuple<Ts...> type;
};

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C : A, B {};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    using direct_base_classes = dbc_as_tuple<tr2::direct_bases<C>::type>::type;

    using first = tuple_element<0, direct_base_classes>::type;
    using second = tuple_element<1, direct_base_classes>::type;

    static_assert(is_same<first, A>::value, "Error!");   // Will not fire
    static_assert(is_same<second, B>::value, "Error!");  // Will not fire
}
```

Comment: Great, that is very close to what I've been looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use `std::bases` (or some similar alternative) under MSVC?