# Getting all base classes [Meta-Programming]

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

Yesterday faced with problem how to get all base classes from some class.
For example:

```
class Object 
{
public:
   Object() = default;
};

class DerivedOne
   : public Object
{
public:
   DerivedOne() = default;
};

class DerivedTwo
   : public Object
   , public DerivedOne
{
public:
   DerivedTwo() = default;
};
```

I want to get all base class for DerivedTwo in typelist => { Object, DerivedOne, Object}
It is needed for deny inheritance from Object class more than one time.

Has somebody such expirience or knowledge how to do it ?

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection yet. You could use the branch of Clang that has a reflection proposal implemented, though.

Comment: The abandoned TR2 had such a trait, and I think GCC implements it. But of course that's not portable.

Comment: @chris Maybe some boost library can do it ?

Comment: @ Kerrek SB: What do you think maybe some boost library can do it ?

Comment: Arbitrary base classes? Or are you allowed to enforce some sort of convention for all base classes?

Comment: @DenisKotov, No, it requires compiler help. The closest you can come would require feeding the library the base classes in some way.

Comment: At run time you want this list ?

Comment: @ Vishal Gupta: Of course at **compile time**

Comment: Maybe you should be able to achieve something with recursive CRTP and let the Base class hold the typelist (flatten a tuple of tuple of...). But that's ugly.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel if you're still around, could you please provide an example on how to achieve that?

Comment: @Fureeish well the problem is that the OP code is invalid (ambiguity) , so just modifying it will give me the same error. And I'd like to know for what use he wanted this, to do somethiung a bit correct.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel I encountered this question because I was looking for a solution (since C++ doesn't offer reflection) for my own problem. Imagine a `template <size_t N> struct foo` and then a `struct bar` that will inherit for example from `foo<16>, foo<64>, foo<32>`. I wanted to somehow get the *biggest* value of `foo`s template value. Any idea how to? The problem of multiple inheritance is the issue here. I kinda want to *iterate over base classes' template values*, but I doubt it's possible. It's easy to access the single value, but I have no idea how to compare an arbitrary number of them

Comment: @Fureeish Sorry I forgot... There is the basic idea, but obviously it need to be adapted to your needs : https://wandbox.org/permlink/MGo9oCmgZGx1Mfvk
Btw, next time open another question :)

Answer (score 0):

The comments mention TR2 reflection proposal which is "abandoned" but yet has an implementation in gcc. The code below is based on SO post: [Finding base class at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798707/finding-base-class-at-compile-time)

### Preparing a tuple to hold the types returned from TR2

```
#include<tr2/type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct types_as_tuple;

template<typename... Ts>
struct types_as_tuple<std::tr2::__reflection_typelist<Ts...>>
{
    typedef std::tuple<Ts...> type;
};
```

### Checking for duplicate type in a tuple

```
template<typename T>
struct duplicate_type;

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
struct duplicate_type<std::tuple<T1, T2, Ts...>> {
    constexpr static bool value = std::is_same<T1, T2>::value
                                  || duplicate_type<std::tuple<T1, Ts...>>::value;
                                  || duplicate_type<std::tuple<T2, Ts...>>::value 
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct duplicate_type<std::tuple<T1, T2>> {
    constexpr static bool value = std::is_same<T1, T2>::value;
};
```

### TypesPrinter

```
template<typename T>
struct TypesPrinter;

template<typename T>
struct TypesPrinter<std::tuple<T>> {
    constexpr TypesPrinter() {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ' ';
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct TypesPrinter<std::tuple<T, Ts...>> {
    constexpr TypesPrinter() {
        TypesPrinter<std::tuple<T>>();
        TypesPrinter<std::tuple<Ts...>>();
    }
};
```

### Main

```
struct A {};
struct B: A {};
struct C {};
struct D : B, C, A {};

int main() {
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // getting all direct and indirect bases of a class with TR2
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    using bases_of_D = types_as_tuple<std::tr2::bases<D>::type>::type;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // checking for duplication at compile time
    // (can also use static_assert)
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    if constexpr(duplicate_type<bases_of_D>::value) {
        std::cout << "duplicate base in class D" << std::endl;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // printing the types
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    TypesPrinter<bases_of_D>();

}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d556c47c660832ff