# Can a class be aware of superclasses when used multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, c++14

I am considering to use multiple inheritance as a part of the design of my library. The user defines components that are described as a *stateless* class (`Component1`, `Component2`, `Component3`) each with the same `typedefs` and static members. See the example of `Component1` below. Other component classes are defined the same way, defining the sub classes, typedefs and static members with the same names.

I also want the user to be able to define the combination of several components as another class (`Combined`). One way of doing it is through the multiple inheritance (see definition below), but I would need the combined class to be automatically aware of the components it was build from. The order of the components matters.

```
struct Component1{
    using MyType = int; //each class defines several standard typedefs
    using return_type = int; 
    struct Parameters {
        constexpr auto static parameter_set = 42;
    }; //classes also define static subclasses
    static return_type myfun(MyType); //and static functions that get defined elsewhere.
};

struct Component2 {/* This class have the same duck-type (public interface) as Base1*/  };

struct Component3 {}; //likewise

struct Combined: public Component1, public Component3, public Component2 {
   //I want this to be automatically generated:
   using members = std::tuple<Component1, Component3, Component2>; 
};
```

Or perhaps there is another way of delivering a similar API?

Comment: It looks like `using Combined = Combine<Component1, Component3, Component2>;` would be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, thank you!!! That is the amazing power of the SO. I got the answer that turns the way I see the problem in just about 1 minute after asking. Now the solution is simple. Thanks again! @Quentin

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't even know how I picked up this drive-by hint dropping habit...

Comment: Highly related question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20798707/2445184 I think, the answer there may help you too.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve the list of base classes from a C++ class (yet?).

However, you could provide a `Combine` class template of the following form:

```
template <class... Components>
struct Combine {
    using members = std::tuple<Components...>;

    // ...
};
```

Which you can then use in the following ways:

```
using Combined = Combine<Component1, Component3, Component2>;
// or
struct Combined : Combine<Component1, Component3, Component2> {
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
template <class... Components>
struct Combine : Components... {
    using members = std::tuple<Components...>;

    template<class... Args>
    Combine(Args&&... args)
        : Components(args...)...
    {}
};

struct A { A(int); };
struct B { B(int); };

struct C : Combine<A, B> {
    using Combine::Combine;
};

int main() {
    C c(1);
}
```